# vbscript, find matches in filenames

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to vbscripting and I just received a task that requires me to find 6 files with matching strings in the filename so that I can move these files to a different directory. I am using the regex pattern "\d{8}-\d{6}" to locate all of the strings within the filenames.

How would I go about in doing a search in a directory and checking to see if there are 6 files with matching strings in their filenames so that I can store them into an array and then move the files to another directory?

The script I have written so far:

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strShareDirectory = "in\"
strDumpStorageDir = "out\"

Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strShareDirectory)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

Set re = New RegExp
re.Global     = True
re.IgnoreCase = False
re.Pattern    = "-\d{8}-\d{6}"

Dim curFile, matchValue
Dim i: i = 0

For Each objFile in colFiles
   bMatch = re.Test(objFile.Name)
   curFile = objFile.Name

   If bMatch Then
      ReDim preserve matches(i)
      Matches(i) = curFile
      i = (i + 1)

      For Each objFile1 in colFiles
        If objFile1.Name <> objFile.Name Then
            For each match in re.Execute(objFile1.Name)
                matchValue = match.Value
                Exit For
            Next
            If (Instr(curFile, matchValue) > 0) Then
                matchCount = 1
                For Each match1 in re.Execute(objFile1.Name)
                    curFile1 = objFile1.Name
                    matchValue1 = match1.Value
                    Exit For
                    'If  Then

                Next
                'msgbox(curFile1)
            End If
     End If
    Next
   End If
Next
```

Here is what my sample directory that I am working with looks like.
[image]

Comment: 1.) I'm a little confused about _what_ should be 6? Do you want to check if the pattern matches six times within one filename?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want to send the files out if there are 6 files with identical digits in the filename.

Comment: Yes, that makes it much clearer ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much!:) I really needed a guidance in figuring out how I would go about solving the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, now I understand.
So: you need all file names that match the pattern IF there are at least 6 files with the same matching sub string. Okay. Then, yes, I understand that you can get strangled up in nested for..next loops. If that happens, I would recommend to put some code into extra functions.
In this solution, I use dictionaries to do some work much easier (every call to 'exists' is another nested iteration over all its elements for example, and every assignment as well).
This example would ignore multiple matches within one file name.

```
option explicit

dim objFS : dim strShareDirectory : dim strDumpStorageDir : dim objFolder : dim colFiles : dim re : dim objFile

dim dictResults ' dictionary of [filename] -> [matching substring]
dim dictResultsCount ' dictionary of [matching substring] -> [count]
dim dictResultsFinal ' only the valid entries from dictResults
dim keyItem 
dim strMatch

set dictResultsFinal = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
set dictResults = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
set dictResultsCount = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strShareDirectory = "in\"
strDumpStorageDir = "out\"

Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strShareDirectory)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

Set re = New RegExp
re.Global     = True
re.IgnoreCase = False
re.Pattern    = "-\d{8}-\d{6}"

Dim curFile, matchValue
Dim i: i = 0

For Each objFile in colFiles
    ' test if the filename matches the pattern
    if re.test(objFile.Name) then
        ' for now, collect all matches without further checks
        strMatch = re.execute(objFile.Name)(0)
        dictResults(objFile.Name) = strMatch
        ' and count
        if not dictResultsCount.Exists(strMatch) then
            dictResultsCount(strMatch) = 1
        else
            dictResultsCount(strMatch) = dictResultsCount(strMatch) +1
        end if
    end if
next

' for testing: output all filenames that match the pattern
msgbox join(dictResults.keys(), vblf)

' now copy only the valid entries into a new dictionary
for each keyItem in dictResults.keys()
    if dictResultsCount.Exists( dictResults(keyItem) ) then
        if dictResultsCount( dictResults(keyItem) ) >= 6 then
            dictResultsFinal(keyItem) = 1
        end if
    end if
next

' test output the final result
msgbox join(dictResultsFinal.keys(), vblf)
```

--- my first answer

Well I should probably ask *what have you tried* but... here's your example ^^.
This should give you enough to start from (I ignored that '6' requirements you mentioned). Ask if you need more explanations.

```
Option explicit
dim a
a = findFiles("G:\",  "\d{8}-\d{6}")
msgbox join(a, vblf)

function findFiles(path, pattern)
    dim rx
    dim fso
    dim fsoFolder
    dim fsoFiles
    dim results
    dim item
    set rx = new regexp
    rx.pattern =  pattern
    set results = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(path)
    set fsoFiles = fsoFolder.Files
    for each item in fsoFiles
        if rx.test(item.name) then results(item.name) = 1
    next
    set fso = nothing
    set fsoFolder = nothing
    set fsoFiles = nothing
    findFiles = results.keys()
end function
```

Answer (score 3):

As @KekuSemau's proposal does not address the (sub)problem of grouping the files, dweebles does not give the full story (Why the array? Why the insistence on having a full (sub)set of files?), and the numbers (group of 6, 3/4 parts in a file name) aren't really relevant to the basic task - distribute a set files into folders based on parts of the file name - I claim that the way to solve the task is to get rid of all the array, dictionary, and regexp fancies and to keep it simple:

Before:

```
tree /A /F ..\data
+---in
|       B-2
|       B-1
|       A-3
|       A-2
|       B-3
|       A-1
|
\---out
```

Code:

```
  Const csSrc = "..\data\in"
  Const csDst = "..\data\out"
  Dim f, n, d
  For Each f In goFS.GetFolder(csSrc).Files
      n = Split(f.Name, "-")
      If 1 = UBound(n) Then
         d = goFS.BuildPath(csDst, n(1))
         If Not goFS.FolderExists(d) Then goFS.CreateFolder d
         f.Move goFS.BuildPath(d, f.Name)
      End If
  Next
```

After:

```
tree /A /F ..\data
+---in
\---out
    +---3
    |       A-3
    |       B-3
    |
    +---1
    |       B-1
    |       A-1
    |
    \---2
            B-2
            A-2
```

**P.S.**
This [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14442413/603855) can be solved using the same approach.

Comment: ^ very True, I really needed a more simple and efficient way to solve this. Thanks!