# Move files with date in the name to date folders

Tags: vbscript

I have a load of files in a folder with a date in the file name.
Can someone create a vbscript to move all the files in the folder to other folders that are named the year from the file name. Also if the folder does not exists to create it.

So if the file is `c:\test\FileName_2012_01_25` it would be moved into a folder named `c:\Sample\2012`

I would be very happy if anyone could help me

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far that isn't working? This is not a site for "will someone please write some code for me to do something?" questions. We expect you to put some effort into solving it yourself first, and then post the code that's not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14407630/603855) to get you started. The change:

```
n = Split(f.Name, "_") ' split on _ instead of -
```

should be the only modification necessary.