# Move files with date in the file name

Tags: date, loops, vbscript

My last post which was my first post on the forum got closed before i even got back to check it so here is my question again in more detail.

```
Const SrcFilePath = "C:\Folder 1\Temp\"

WScript.echo "SrcFilePath = " & SrcFilePath

Const FileExtension = ".txt"

newdate = date()-1

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            If Day(newdate)>9 Then
                            ExtensionDay = Day(newdate)
            Else
                            ExtensionDay = "0"&Day(newdate)
            End If

            If Month(newdate)>9 Then
                            ExtensionMonth = Month(newdate)
            Else
                            ExtensionMonth = "0"&Month(newdate)
            End If

            If Year(newdate)>9 Then
                            ExtensionYear = Year(newdate)
            Else
                            ExtensionYear = Year(newdate)
            End If

Mon = MonthName(ExtensionMonth, true)
Yer = Right(ExtensionYear,2)

DateTag = ExtensionDay & "_" & ExtensionMonth & "_" & ExtensionYear

DateTag1 = ExtensionYear

DestFileName = "Test File_" & DateTag & FileExtension

WScript.echo DestFileName

SrcFile = SrcFilePath  & "Test File_" & DateTag & FileExtension

Dest_File = "D:\Test 1\" & ExtensionYear & "\"

WScript.echo "Copy from =" & SrcFile, "Copy to =" & Dest_File

Fso.CopyFile SrcFile, Dest_File
```

The code above will get a file that has yesterday’s date in the file name and move it to the folder with the year from the file.

Here is what I would like it to do

“C:\Folder 1\Temp\” folder has the following files in it

C:\Folder 1\Temp\Test 1_2012_10_25.txt

C:\Folder 1\Temp\Test 2_2013_08_25.txt

C:\Folder 1\Temp\Test 3_2011_10_25.txt

C:\Folder 1\Temp\Test 4_2010_10_25.txt

I would like these files moved to folders based on the File name and Year from the file name like below. My code above only does 1 file for yesterday’s Date. I would like it to loop through and organize all files in the folder.

C:\Folder 1\Temp\Test 1_2012_10_25.txt > D:\Test 1\2012\ Test 1_2012_10_25.txt

C:\Folder 1\Temp\Test 2_2013_08_25.txt > D:\Test 2\2013\ Test 2_2013_08_25.txt

C:\Folder 1\Temp\Test 1_2012_10_25.txt > D:\Test 3\2011\ Test 3_2012_10_25.txt

C:\Folder 1\Temp\Test 1_2012_10_25.txt > D:\Test 1\2012\ Test 1_2012_10_25.txt

Also if the folders On D:\ don’t exist then to create them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still claim that a slight modification of the code in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14407630/603855):

```
  Const csSrc = "..\data\in2"
  Const csDst = "..\data\out2"
  Dim f, n, d
  For Each f In goFS.GetFolder(csSrc).Files
      n = Split(f.Name, "_") ' split on _ instead of -
      If 3 = UBound(n) Then  ' 4 parts instead of 2
         d = goFS.BuildPath(csDst, n(1))
         If Not goFS.FolderExists(d) Then goFS.CreateFolder d
         f.Move goFS.BuildPath(d, f.Name)
      End If
  Next
```

solves your problem. Evidence:

```
tree /a /f ..\data\in2
    Test 7_2012_11_25.txt
    Test 1_2010_11_25.txt
    Test 2_2010_12_25.txt
    Test 9_2012_13_25.txt
    Test 8_2012_12_25.txt
    Test 3_2010_13_25.txt
    Test 6_2011_13_25.txt
    Test 4_2011_11_25.txt
    Test 5_2011_12_25.txt

tree /a /f ..\data\out2
+---2011
|       Test 6_2011_13_25.txt
|       Test 4_2011_11_25.txt
|       Test 5_2011_12_25.txt
|
+---2010
|       Test 1_2010_11_25.txt
|       Test 2_2010_12_25.txt
|       Test 3_2010_13_25.txt
|
\---2012
        Test 7_2012_11_25.txt
        Test 9_2012_13_25.txt
        Test 8_2012_12_25.txt
```

**Update - use first ("Test n") part of file name for parent folder of year directory:**

Just apply the same strategy:

```
  For Each f In goFS.GetFolder(csSrc).Files
      n = Split(f.Name, "_")
      If 3 = UBound(n) Then
         d = goFS.BuildPath(csDst, n(0))
         If Not goFS.FolderExists(d) Then goFS.CreateFolder d
         d = goFS.BuildPath(d, n(1))
         If Not goFS.FolderExists(d) Then goFS.CreateFolder d
         f.Move goFS.BuildPath(d, f.Name)
      End If
  Next
```

Comment: Hi Ekkehard Thanks for the reply. My knowledge of programming isnt that good but I'm getting an error Object required: 'goFS'.

Comment: I needed to add this line    Dim goFS  : Set goFS  = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" ). It works now but the folder its creating is not the year but the number 20

Comment: Just tested it again and that works fine. I have 1 more request. Is it possible to create a folder with the first part of the file name as well like Test 6 then the Year so all test 6 or 7 or 8 files are together in the relevant Year folder. Thanks Again.

Comment: That works great. Thanks for your help you saved me a lot of time.