# VBS to open a file by part of name run on the network drive but not local

Tags: excel, windows, vbscript

How are you?

I have a vbs like below that works normally on files that are on network drives but does not work when the file is on my pc.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurDir = WshShell.CurrentDirectory

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

with objExcel
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .visible = True
end with

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strCurDir & "\4_?????.xlsb")

'Save the workbook
objWorkbook.Save

'close the workbook
objWorkbook.Close

with objExcel
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .visible = True
end with

'exit the excel program
objExcel.Quit

'release objects
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
```

Where "?????" it's a timestamp. In this case, I know that the file starts with "4_" and has the extension ".xlsb" and my timestamp is 5 characters long. Soon the "?????" I used to "escape" this timestamp that changes continuously.

Note: I did a test, removing the "?????" and putting the timestamp that is today and it works on my machine. So for some reason my computer doesn't recognize the "?????" pattern.

Can someone help me find out why this script doesn't work for files that are local?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (Excel)Workbooks.Open expects a file path, not a pattern. The easiest way to get what you want is to get list of files in the folder and check each name if it  fits your pattern, for example:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dir = fs.GetFolder(strCurDir)
Set ff = dir.Files
For Each f in ff
    if left(f.Name,2)="4_" and right(f.Name,5)=".xlsb" then
           Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(f.Path) 
           ...
    end if 
Next
```

Alternatively, you can use [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403269/vbscript-find-matches-in-filenames).

Comment: Oh Thank you! But why in a network drive (not locally) Workbook.Open accepts patterns and locally not?